# Python imports - current package name before period?

Tags: python, python-import

In the [flask tutorial](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/blueprints/#registering-blueprints), the following package structure is used:

```
yourapplication/__init__.py
yourapplication/simple_page.py
```

Now, in `__init.py`, the following import is done:

`from yourapplication.simple_page import simple_page`

Can anyone explain to me why the `yourapplication` before the `.` is there? I thought you could just do

`from .simple_page import simple_page`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can anyone explain to me why the yourapplication before the . is there?

this is done to tell that the yourapplication is the base of the project from where one need to start working. it make absolute to the project path and make yourapplication as source directory.

but if this method not use , and relative import used like `from .simple_page import simple_page`, then if simple page file is removed and refactored into different folder and `__init__` file also then it become hard to debug.

using `from yourapplication.simple_page import simple_page` this way will tell the full structure of project and all the import are made from the source directory level, which make it easy to refactor in later stage.

overall: in one sentence it is just for maintaining, scaling  the project.

you can you relative import and absolute import, using this way one can tell the whole project structre and in refactor time it take time to refactor code if project design change, compare to which in relative import refactor take less time

Answer (score 0):

dot represent the current working direct so in python code in import statement programmers use dot before script statement. In your case, your package name is yourapplication so you can use dot during the import statement.

`yourapplication/simple_page.py
yourapplication/__init__.py
dot = yourapplication`

```
from .simple_page import simple_page
```